# What is the definition of "Sideline" in reference to aircraft noise?

Tags: noise

The FAA has measured external aircraft noise levels and published the results in the Advisory Circular:

[AC 36-1H - Noise Levels for U.S. Certificated and Foreign Aircraft](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2036-1H.pdf)

In the appendices, noise levels are listed for Takeoff (TO), Sideline (SL) and Approach (AP).

I understand the concept of Takeoff and Approach, but what is "Sideline"?   It is not defined in the document, nor does it show up in a search of the  [Code of Federal Regulations.](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/ECFR?page=browse)

Comment: Your document mentions a 450m distance on page 3.  See also http://adg.stanford.edu/aa241/noise/far36.txt mentioning more detail under C36.9(c)

Comment: More on the noise measurement: [Noise Certification Workshop](http://www.icao.int/Meetings/EnvironmentalWorkshops/Documents/Noise-Certification-Workshop-2006/Boettcher_3.pdf) and [ICAO Doc 9501 Procedures for the Noise Certification of Aircraft](http://www.icao.int/environmental-protection/Documents/SGAR.2015.ETM.Vol.1.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definitions are specific.
(They are defined in **FAR Part 36**).
I'm writing also the Take-off and approach noise definitions just for your information.

> **Sideline noise:** is defined and measured 1476 ft (450 m) from the runway centerline at a point where the noise level after liftoff is greatest.

> **Take-off noise:** is defined as the noise measured at a distance of 21,325 ft (6500 m) from the start of the take-off roll,
>   directly under the airplane.

> **Approach noise:** is also defined and measured under the airplane when it is at a distance of 6562 ft (2000 m) from the runway threshold.

For each of these conditions the maximum noise level is a function of maximum takeoff gross weight, and for the take-off case the limits depend also on the number of engines.